# How do I extract all results from a GET request that spans multiple pages?

Tags: python, json, dataframe, python-requests, append

I have successfully written code that calls an API and then converts the results into a DataFrame.

```
wax_wallet = "zqsfm.wam"

# Get Assets from AtomicHub API
response1 = requests.get(
    "https://wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/assets?"
    f"owner={wax_wallet}"
    "&collection_whitelist=nftdraft2121"
    "&page=1"
    "&limit=1000"
    "&order=asc"
    "&sort=name")

# Save Response as JSON
json_assets = response1.json()

# Convert JSON to DataFrame
df = pd.json_normalize(json_assets['data'])
```

This API returns at most 1000 items per page so I need to have it loop through as many pages as needed and ultimately get the results stored into a DataFrame.

I attempted to solve it with the below code, but was unsuccessful.

```
asset_count = 2500
pages = int(math.ceil(asset_count / 1000))

# Get Assets from AtomicHub API
all_assets = []
for page in range(1, pages):
    url = f'https://wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/assets?owner={wax_wallet}' \
          f'&collection_whitelist=nftdraft2121&page={page}&limit=1000&order=asc&sort=name'
    response = rq.get(url)
    all_assets.append(json.loads(response.text))["response"]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's better to use `params` argument rather then form query string manually: `requests.get("https://wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/assets", params={"owner": wax_wallet, "collection_whitelist": "nftdraft2121", "page": "1", "limit": "1000", "order": "asc", "sort": "name")`. Also you can use [`response.json()`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn them into dataframes and then concatenate the individual frames into a final result:

```
def get_page(page_num):
    wax_wallet = "zqsfm.wam"

    response = requests.get(
        "https://wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/assets",
        params={
            "owner": wax_wallet,
            "collection_whitelist": "nftdraft2121",
            "page": page_num,
            "limit": "1000",
            "order": "asc",
            "sort": "name"
        }
    )

    json_assets = response.json()
    return pd.json_normalize(json_assets['data'])

# The number of pages you want
number_of_pages_requested = 10

# Get all pages as dataframes
pages = [get_page(n + 1) for n in range(number_of_pages_requested)]

# Combine pages to single dataframe
df = pd.concat(pages)
```

*Edit:* updated using params based on **Olvin Roght**'s comment

*Edit 2:* fixed indexing error

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your question. But good suggestion using params

Comment: You already edited your answer including my suggestion from comments, so my question has no point now. I've just wanted to point you that you need to encode each value to url encoding if you're forming url manually and it's better to use `params` which will do this internally.

Comment: @tituszban Thanks for the response! This works almost perfectly; however, it is not returning exactly what I am hoping for. I need to return 3 pages but this code is returning the first page twice and then the second page once.

For example, I have 2,500 items spanned across 3 pages. This output is returning 1-1000, 1-1000, then 1,001-2,000.

Any ideas?

Comment: @python_noob_5, use  `range(1, number_of_pages_requested + 1)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght is correct. I prefer doing `n + 1`. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:-

```
import requests

all_assets = []
URL = 'https://wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/assets'
params = {
    'owner': 'zqsfm.wam',
    'collection_whitelist': 'nftdraft2121',
    'page': 1,
    'order': 'asc',
    'sort': 'name',
    'limit': 1000
}
with requests.Session() as session:
    while True:
        print(f"Getting page {params['page']}")
        response = session.get(URL, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()
        _j = response.json()
        data = _j['data']
        if len(data) > 0:
            all_assets.append(data)
            params['page'] += 1
        else:
            break
print('Done')
```

Comment: Better to avoid variable names which could possibly shadow imports. Also infinity loops is mostly bad pattern, it's better to add some strict condition.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the variable named 'json'. On the basis that I don't import json, I don't see the problem. Also, in this particular case, there is no way of knowing how many pages might be returned. It can only be deduced by asking for a page that's outside of the available range and, when that happens, a well-defined condition arises